# Find the first null value in a breadth-wide search of a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, binary-heap

I'm trying to write a binary heap implemented over a binary tree, but I'm having trouble finding a way to add a new node to the "bottom" of the heap, i.e. the first null space on the tree in a breadth-first traversal. I've already got a working heapify function, but I can't figure out how to add a new node before heapifying.

I can't seem to think of a consistent algorithm that can find the null space that I can add my node to, every time I think I come up with something, it doesn't work. What do I do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780152/how-to-insert-into-a-binary-max-heap-implemented-as-a-binary-tree/14780554#14780554

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an element to the first non-occupied leaf in a binary tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204556/adding-an-element-to-the-first-non-occupied-leaf-in-a-binary-tree)